# Alloy Model diagram functionality and cardinality symbols

Tags: alloy

I am using the Alloy Analyzer 4.2 (build date: 2012-09-25 15:54 EDT). I have read in section 4.3 of the [Alloy Book](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/book.html) devoted to Model Diagrams that the analyzer could generate model diagrams using the multiplicity symbols !,?,*and+. However I cannot find the proper way to use and/or make these symbols be used by the analyzer. I guess the "Execute>show metamodel" functionality is the one in fact described by the book, but the symbols can't be used nor are displayed.
I have tried the following :

Try 1 :

```
sig A {
attributeA : one B
}

sig B {
attributeB : set C
}

sig C {
attributeC : lone A
}

pred show {}
run show
```

generates a symbol-less metamodel:
[metamodel using multiplicity keywords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5V1S0.png)

Try 2:

```
sig A {
attributeA : ! B
}

sig B {
attributeB : * C
}

sig C {
attributeC : ? A
}

pred show {}
run show
```

yields this parsing error message (about the '?'):

```
Syntax error at line 10 column 14:
Syntax error at the ? character.
```

Try 3 :

```
sig A {
attributeA : ! B
}

sig B {
attributeB : * C
}

sig C {
attributeC : ! A
}

pred show {}
run show
```

yields this type-checking error message (about the first '!'):

```
Starting the solver...

A type error has occurred:
This expression failed to be typechecked
```

How does one get the model diagram functionality to display/use cardinality symbols?

Comment: interesting question.
I'm not sure this is implemented in the current version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated diagram doesn't include multiplicity symbols, unfortunately.